# Cassandra table creation fails with Bad Request: mismatched input

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, cqlsh

I have created a Cassandra keyspace tracker:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE tracker WITH replication = {
  'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
  'replication_factor': '3'
};
```

And then I can create a table in this keyspace successfully:

```
cqlsh:tracker> CREATE TABLE tracker.click_windows (
           ...   visitor_id text,
           ...   created_at timeuuid,
           ...   click_id text,
           ...   ended_at timeuuid,
           ...   expires_at timeuuid,
           ...   processed_at timeuuid,
           ...   window_size int,
           ...   PRIMARY KEY (visitor_id, created_at)
           ... ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_at DESC) AND
           ...   bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
           ...   caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
           ...   comment='' AND
           ...   dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
           ...   gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
           ...   read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
           ...   replicate_on_write='true' AND
           ...   populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
           ...   compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
           ...   compression={'sstable_compression': 'SnappyCompressor'};
```

But when I go to add the next table/column family I get an error:

```
cqlsh> CREATE TABLE tracker.clicks (
   ...   id text PRIMARY KEY,
   ...   created_at timeuuid,
   ...   data map
   ... ) WITH
   ...   bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
   ...   caching='ALL' AND
   ...   comment='' AND
   ...   dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
   ...   gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
   ...   read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
   ...   replicate_on_write='true' AND
   ...   populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
   ...   compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
   ...   compression={'sstable_compression': 'SnappyCompressor'};
Bad Request: line 5:0 mismatched input ')' expecting '<'
```

I found some indication that this could be a CQL version problem, but when I start cqlsh with `--cql3` this still occurs. I don't see anything obvious about these two that are so different that one works and the other doesn't. I also have additional ones not working, like

```
cqlsh> CREATE TABLE tracker.session_hits (
   ...   session_id timeuuid,
   ...   hit_id timeuuid,
   ...   click_id text,
   ...   created_at timeuuid,
   ...   data map,
   ...   visitor_id text,
   ...   window_ids list,
   ...   PRIMARY KEY (session_id, hit_id)
   ... ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (hit_id DESC) AND
   ...   bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
   ...   caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
   ...   comment='' AND
   ...   dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
   ...   gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
   ...   read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
   ...   replicate_on_write='true' AND
   ...   populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
   ...   compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
   ...   compression={'sstable_compression': 'SnappyCompressor'};
Bad Request: line 8:17 mismatched input ',' expecting '<'
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to parametrize your collections' (map/list) definitions

http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#types

```
<collection-type> ::= list '<' <native-type> '>'
                    | set  '<' <native-type> '>'
                    | map  '<' <native-type> ',' <native-type> '>'
```

Comment: you're right. upon inspection, i realized they got dropped when they were copied from the DSE web interface, which failed to escape the `<` and `>` so they were swallowed up as html tags.